# Docker enterprise installation on CIS AMI of windows 2016 server

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, ansible, package-management, ansible-playbook

I am trying to install the Docker enterprise edition on CIS AMI of windows 2016 server using ansible. I am using PowerShell module for this installation. The code is as below for the docker installation task.

```
- name: Install Docker for windows.
  win_shell: >
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12";
    Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -confirm:$false -Force;
    Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -confirm:$false –Force
  when: ecs_docker == True
```

This is inside CI-CD and code get executed on circleci docker image. Above task fails giving below message.

```
Install-Module : NuGet provider is required to interact with NuGet-based repositories.
```

To install Nuget package manager, I have included below task.

```
- name: Install Nuget repository.
  win_chocolatey:
    name: nugetpackagemanager
    state: present
```

Still message is same. Above task completes installation of Nuget package manager.
There is another message which is as below.

```
Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and \r\nPrompt functionality is not available
```

I added `-force` parameter as well for forceful installation of docker however it fails the build. I am building windows based docker images which I am going to host on this 2016 server.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my ansible task with another PowerShell command for docker installation. Below is the updated task definition. I just added Nuget package provider.

```
- name: Install Docker for windows.
  win_shell: >
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12";
    Install-PackageProvider NuGet -Force;
    Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -confirm:$false -Force;
    Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -confirm:$false –Force
  when: ecs_docker == True
```